# Meaning of identity in category theory

Tags: category-theory

Reading definitions of a Category, [like on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category_theory#Categories), I start to wonder what the identity morphism actually means in the following sense:

Purely formally, I understand that for object $A$ the identity $id_A$ just associates $A$ to itself, like a single ordered pair $(A,A)$.

Yet the objects of a Category often have structure in that they contain elements. So lets suppose the object $A$ is indeed a set. Does the Category definition of $id_A$ then require that it maps each element of $a\in A$ to itself, i.e. $id_A(a) = a\,\forall a\in A$, or could $id_A$ in principle be a permutation (or some other map) of the elements of $A$ and still be the identity morphism for $A$ on the Category level? Or in another twist: can we prove that $id_A$ must be the identity map on the set level anyway?

Comment: Well, when the maps in the category are functions, then since $id_A\circ id_A=id_A$ the function can’t be a non-identity permutation.

Comment: (My head starts spinning :-) Suppose $1\in A$ and we define $id_A(a) = 1$, then $id_A(id_A(a))=1=id_A(a)\, \forall a\in A$ so $id_A \circ id_A = id_A$?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I changed the question slightly after your comment because, yes, for the specific case of $id_A$ as a permutation your argument holds, but my question was intended to be more general, so I tried to clarify it.

Comment: Don't forget the identity morphism also satisfies $id_A \circ g = g$ for morphisms $g:B \to A$  and $h \circ id_A = h$ for morphisms $h:A \to C$. This prevents $id_A$ from being a non-trivial permutation in the category of sets.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your objects are sets and your maps are functions with the usual composition, you can have such a category where $id_A$ is not always the identity function.

However, in some sense, such a category is equivalent to a category with identity functions.

Let $\mathcal C$ be your category.

Let $X(A)$ be the image of $id_A$ for each object $A.$ Given any map $f:A\to B,$ since $id_B\circ f=f,$ we see that all the functions $f$ have a range in $X(B).$ So this means we get a function $X(f):X(A)\to X(B).$

Now, $X(f)$ along with $id_A$ fully determines the function $f,$ So this means that if $f\neq g$ then $X(f)\neq X(g).$

Finally, show that $X(f_1\circ f_2)=X(f_1)\circ X(f_2)$ when $f_1,f_2$ are compatible.

Then we can replace $\mathcal C$ with a category $\mathcal D$ whose objects are $X(A)$ and maps are the functions $X(f)$ and identities $X(id_A).$

But $X(id_A)$ is the identity function on $X(A).$

Intuitively, what you have in your representation of $\mathcal C$ is sets which potentially have “more elements” than are needed to represent $\mathcal C.$ Once we restrict the sets to the relevant elements, you get identity maps.

---

**An Example**

Given a field, $k,$ we can consider the category of spaces with projections. Objects are pairs $(V,p_V)$ where $V$ is a vector space and $p_V:V\to V$ is a projection. That is, a linear map with $p_V\circ p_V= p_V.$

The maps $(V,p_V)\to (W,p_W)$ are linear functions $f:V\to W$ with $f\circ p_V=p_W\circ f = f.$ Then the identity on $(V,p_V)$ is just $p_V.$

In this category, some identities will be identity functions - namely, when $p_V$ is the identity.

This works in any base category represented by sets. If $\mathcal D$ is a category which has objects represented by sets and maps represented by functions on those sets, then we can define the category $\mathcal C$ as the category of all pairs $(D,p_D)$ with $D$ an object of $\mathcal D$ and $p_D$ a map $D\circ D$ such that $p_D\circ p_D=p_D$ and maps defined similar to above.

---

In functor terms, this can be written as $\mathcal C^{\mathcal P},$ the category of functors from $\mathcal P$ to $\mathcal C$ where $\mathcal P$ is a category with one object, $\cdot,$ and two maps $\cdot\to\cdot,$ $i$ and $p,$ with $i\circ i=i, p\circ i=i\circ p=p\circ p=p.$

---

At heart, this means if you have something like a functor $F_0:\mathcal C\to \mathcal{Set},$ which does not send identities to identities, but otherwise satisfies the conditions for a functor, then what you really have is a functor $F:\mathcal C\to\mathcal{Set}^{\mathcal P}.$ We can then reduce it back to a functor to sets with $(S,p_S)$ sent to $p_S(S).$

If $F_0$ is "faithful," then the $F$ is also a faithful functor, and the reduction to a functor to $\mathcal{Sets}$ is also faithful.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer to your twists questions:
*"Or in another twist: can we prove that $id_A$ must be the identity map on the set level anyway?"*

Yes. I am assuming you (like me) define two functions to be equal when they give same output for the same input (and obviously if they have different domains or different codomain then they are different).

Now let's pay close attention to the definition of an identity arrow in a category:

Let $\mathscr{C}$ be your category. Let $a$ be a $\mathscr{C}$-objects. The identity arrow on $a$ is defined to be the arrow (you can say an arrow but then you can prove it's unique so we say *the* arrow) $id_a:a \rightarrow a$ such that for **any** arrow $f:b \rightarrow a$ (where $b$ is a $\mathscr{C}$-object which could potentially be $a$ itself) $id_a \circ f = f$ **and** (at the same time) for **any** arrow $g:a \rightarrow c$ (where $c$ is a $\mathscr{C}$-object which could potentially be $a$ itself) $g \circ id_a = g$.

Now,let's say you are in a category whose objects are sets and arrows are functions. Let's say $A$ is an object of this category. The **only** arrow (function) from $A$ to $A$ that has the property mentioned above is the identity function on the set $A$ since it has to work for **any** function coming to $A$ and going out from $A$. Even if your category only has one object (namely this set $A$), the only function having the property of an identity arrow is the identity function. (You may say hang on a min, what if I only have one set A with say 3 elements and only one arrow from A to A which is a non-trivial permutation (let's call it $f:A \rightarrow A$) then the only composition is $f \circ f$ and... oops $f \circ f$ is not equal to $f$ since it gives different output for the same input. nevermind!)

Long answer to the first part your question:

In think your confusion may come because you think the category definition is **directly** forcing the $id_A$ to be the function to send each **element** to itself when the objects of that category are sets.

Note the category doesn't care about the internal structure of its objects. **It doesn't even care about what the definition of equality of its arrows is**. So as far as the category is concerned, the definition of equality of arrows could be anything as long as arrows with different domains or different codomains are marked as different.

So basically the category says, give me a bunch of objects, give me a bunch of arrows between those objects, **give me a definition of equality of arrows**, give me a rule for composition of arrows (which is compatible with my abstarct composition law), give me an identity arrow on each object (which is compatible with my abstract identity law). Then I am a category and then every theory proved for an abstract category also applies to you.

Yes, the category says, in my definition of identity I am using equality of arrows, but the definition of equality is coming from you not me (again as long as your definition is in such a way that arrows with different domain or different codomains are marked not equal).

So category is not forcing the definition of equality of arrows on you. What it is forcing is whatever your definition of equality of arrows is, the identity arrow needs to follow my rules.

Now when we are talking about sets and functions, the standard definition of equality of functions is: function $f$ is equal to function $g$ if it gives same output for the same input.

So if we take this standard definition as our definition of equality and go to the category theory then it forces us to follow its identity rule, then the only choice for identity arrow is to choose identity function on a set.

Now let's say you somehow (I don't know how) come up with a different definition of equality of functions (which is well-behaved: at **least** based on that hypothetical definition one should be able to define an equivalence relation of functions), then the identity arrow could potentially be something other than the identity function.

So in summary, the category is not **directly** forcing the identity arrow for a set to be the identity function (because in order to directly do that, it needs to know internal structure of its object which it doesn't care about). What is forcing this to be the case is the abstract definition of identity arrow in which definition of equality of arrows is used. And for the functions, the definition of equality of arrows is: give same output for the same input. These together force identity function to be the only candidate for the identity arrow.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a permutation then it's considered an isomorphism of the sets $A\simeq B$ in the category $\textbf{Set}$ where they've naturally and conventionally defined each $\text{id}_A$ to be the identity *function* on the set or the function that just returns its argument.  Of course that is equal to the identity *permutation*.  The set of all permutations $\text{Aut}(A)$ is a group under function composition.

Since you have an isomorphism, you can always replace $A$ by $B$ in further theoretical computations, except that you have to change any involved $=$ into an $\simeq$ (that occur "higher up" in the expression tree) whenever you do that.

So equality implies isomorphism, but isomorphism does not neccessarilly imply equality, unless of course you're working with a new type of mathematics under "Univalent Foundations."  I don't know how it works there, and it may not be as simple as always replacing $\simeq$ with $=$.

Now identity is cool, because its an inhabitant of each $\text{Hom}(A,A)$ so that the homsets with same domain as codomain are always populated with *something*.  This becomes important later, because you then (as in the proof of Yoneda, which is used everywhere) take $\text{id}_A$ and then $\eta(\text{id}_A)$ for appropriate $\eta$ and the fact that it *is the identity* becomes important when you need to show that certain diagrams indeed commute.